# How can a linux kernel be so small?

Tags: linux, kernel

An ordinary stable 3* kernel is about 70 mb now. 
But there are little linux distributions of 30-10 mb with software and other stuff running out of the box.

How can the linux kernel be so small in these distros?
Can stripping down only unneeded modules and drivers dramatically reduce the size? 
What else is done to reduce the kernel size?

Comment: Another option is to use size optimizations when compiling, but I'm not sure how big impact can that make.

Comment: "Linus calls Linux 'bloated and huge'" http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/09/22/linus_torvalds_linux_bloated_huge/

Comment: @AndrejaKo - A lot. (If you go for small size.)

Comment: 70 MB is the size of the source. A standard compiled and compressed kernel is around 2 MB, modules like 10 MB.

Comment: yes, indeed, its 3.6 mb while initramfs is 21mb in my distro.

Comment: As ott-- pointed out there is no kernel image of 70MB, that's surely the size of the sources!

Comment: 2MB?  That's nothing - I have seen Tetris coded in [less than half a kilobyte](http://www.scene.org/file.php?file=/mags/hugi/compos/hc22fin.zip&fileinfo) :)

Comment: 70 MB is not the size of the source. These really are the binaries. The Debian kernel ships with over 3000 modules, some of which are multiple megabytes in size. The current source tree is almost 900 MiB.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft there are a lot [boot sector games](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UzTf0Qo37A) out there

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes.

- If you strip them down (compile only modules for the things that you actually need.)
- Optimize the kernel for size (ie.: -Os)
- Compress the kernel (such as XZ.)

These "options" are all available in the standard kernel and you can do this at the configuration step. You don't need any kind of special tool.

Using those three things will result in such a small kernel. You can make even smaller ones, for a targeted system. Like I know my PC, I know my stuff. So I'll just compile what I need. Like my own SATA drivers, a driver for USB, etc. Nothing else. No webcam, no old IDE drives, nothing.

The bigger ones you encounter are the WHOLE kernel. They are compiled with the most generic options to be able to run on most hardware without issues and they contain almost every driver available as modules. These modules don't make the kernel slower speed-wise as the modules are loaded on-demand.

(There are 3 states for modules at the configuration stage:
`[ ]` - Won't get compiled, won't be part of your kernel.
`[M]` - Will be compiled as a module.
(You can modprobe it, or your system will auto-load it when it's needed.
Depends on the system, userland.)
`[X]` - It'll be compiled into the kernel AND will be present - always.

Distros with small but still generic kernel:

- [Tiny Core Linux, Micro Core Linux, 12MB Linux GUI Desktop, Live,
  Frugal, Extendable](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/welcome.html)
- [Puppy Linux Community Home - Getting Started](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm)

Comment: Just a small addition - [X] means it'll be compiled **into** the kernel, hence the reason why it's always loaded.

Comment: "newbies expect" speaking as a professional computer tech and Linux veteran of 20 years... I expect things to just work too.

Answer (score 22):

Early Linux distributions such as [Tom's Root-Boot](http://www.toms.net/rb/), [MuLinux](http://www.linfo.org/mulinux), [Diet-router](http://maxrelax.de/~tmueller/diet-router.html), (the now defunct) [LOAF](http://linux.about.com/cs/linux101/g/loaf.htm) and many others now departed, all fit a working Linux system on one or two 1.44 MB diskettes.

The Linux kernel has grown but it is modular: kernel modules are loaded as needed. Thus it is still possible to produce a Linux distribution with a very small footprint.

See: [Kernel Size Tuning Guide - eLinux.org](http://elinux.org/Kernel_Size_Tuning_Guide)

If you read [Linux_tiny.pdf](http://elinux.org/images/7/72/Linux_tiny.pdf)  you will see this

- historic 0.99pl15 kernel: Slackware 1.1.2, 1994: **301K**
- Fedora Core 2:  **1.2M**
- SuSE 9.1:  **1.5M**
- 2.6.5-tiny1 test config: IDE, ext2, TCP, NIC:  **363K**

Answer (score 11):

The default kernel configuration is configured to support as many hardware as possible. A non-stripped kernel with default configuration resulted in a size of 1897996 kB (including kernel + modules). When stripping many unnecessary drivers and options (why would I need a HP module if I own a Clevo notebook), it resulted in a size of 892892 kB which is a size reduction of 53% compared to the stock kernel.

When installing the kernel modules, append the `INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1` option. This will strip all debugging symbols and reduced the size by 92% for me (from 892892 kB to 69356 kB). Note this will only affects modules to be installed and not the kernel (vmlinuz) itself:

```
make INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1 modules_install
```

From [Documentation/kbuild/kbuild.txt](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kbuild/kbuild.txt#144):

```
INSTALL_MOD_STRIP
--------------------------------------------------
INSTALL_MOD_STRIP, if defined, will cause modules to be
stripped after they are installed.  If INSTALL_MOD_STRIP is '1', then
the default option --strip-debug will be used.  Otherwise,
INSTALL_MOD_STRIP value will be used as the options to the strip command.
```

Comment: wow, 1897996 kB is almost 2GB!

Comment: I very much doubt this information is accurate. It is most likely the size of the source tree after compilation. It contains many intermediate build artifacts that are not part of the actual “installation tree” of a kernel.

Answer (score 3):

Most major distros configure their kernels with maximum hardware support so it will work out of the box with most computers and anything you plug in later on. They also use an initrd system which is not needed in most cases. There are also options in the kernel configuration that make the build process optimize for size, and a better (though slower) compression method can be selected as well. Lastly, if you are looking at the size of the kernel source code, keep in mind that it also includes support for several architectures beyond x86/amd64, network protocols, file systems, and other features that you'll probably never use and that can be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple, a minimal system just need bootloader + kernel though it is almost useless. Most of commands used everyday, are optional binary for the system, like sh, ls, etc.  If you are interested in internals, [Linux From Scratch!](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) is a good start point.

Comment: Note that Busybox takes care of most of the "everyday" stuff.

Comment: No, busybox just combined them together. It is popular in small and embedded system, but not the case for desktop system.